# Deciphering cgminer interface in terminal

Tags: cgminer

Am brand new to mining, and wanted to download an OSX miner just to experience (fully realizing that it would not be profitable). With cgminer connected to a mining pool, I see the following interface...
[image: cgminer screenshot]

... Can someone help me understand what each of the indicators mean (A, R, HW, WU, ST, SS, NB, LW, GF, RF)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Bitcoin Forum > Bitcoin > Mining > Mining software (miners) (Moderators: gmaxwell, MiningBuddy) > CGMINER ASIC FPGA miner monitoring fanspeed RPC linux/win/osx/mip/arm/r-pi 3.9.0](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=28402.0)

Cite:

```
A:   The number of Accepted shares
R:   The number of Rejected shares
HW:  The number of HardWare errors
WU:   The Work Utility defined as the number of diff1 equivalent shares / minute


 AVA 0: 23C/ 47C 2280R | 77.10G/83.20Gh/s | A:120029 R:0 HW:2295 WU:1162.5/m

Each column is as follows:
Temperature (if supported)
Fanspeed (if supported)
A 5 second exponentially decaying average hash rate
An all time average hash rate
The number of accepted shares
The number of rejected shares
The number of hardware erorrs
The Work Utility defined as the number of diff1 equivalent shares / minute

The cgminer status line shows:
 TQ: 1  ST: 1  SS: 0  DW: 0  NB: 1  LW: 8  GF: 1  RF: 1

TQ is Total Queued work items.
ST is STaged work items (ready to use).
SS is Stale Shares discarded (detected and not submitted so don't count as rejects)
DW is Discarded Work items (work from block no longer valid to work on)
NB is New Blocks detected on the network
LW is Locally generated Work items
GF is Getwork Fail Occasions (server slow to provide work)
RF is Remote Fail occasions (server slow to accept work)
```